# Image height-width to change according to image size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I would like to implement the media query when image size is 50x100 media query would like image height-100px width-100px, similarly if image size is 100x50 
image height-90px width-90px

I know media query for screen size only. if it is possible please suggest to fix my project.

```
eg
@media img-src (min-width:50px ) and (max-width:100px) {
.imagediv {
    width: 100x;
    height: 100px;
} }
```

Comment: You don't think about bootstrap?

Comment: I familar with bootstrap. but our projects inbuilt application I mean. its inbuilt software. I have to customize it.